# How to make this loop faster in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab

I have to multiply arrays `A` and `B` element by element and calculate the sum of the first dimension, then returns the result in `C`. `A` is a `N`-by-`M`-by-`L` matrix. `B` is a `N`-by-`1`-by-`L` matrix. `N` and `M` is lower than `30`, but `L` is very large. My code is:

```
C=zeros(size(B));
parfor i=1:size(A,2)
    C(i,1,:) = sum(bsxfun(@times, A(:,i,:), B(:,1,:)), 1);
end
```

The problem is the code is slow, anyone can help to make the code faster? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of this:

```
C = permute(sum(A.*repmat(B,1,M)),[2,1,3]);
```

This speeds computation on my PC up by a factor of ~4. Interestingly enough, you can actually speed up the computation by a factor of 2 (at least on my PC) simply by changing the `parfor` loop to a `for` loop.

Comment: It should be the non-conjugate transpose ``.'`` in case the elements are complex.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the transpose at all, because transpose is not defined for a 3D matrix. Permute is a better idea, and it doesn't seem to give a performance hit at all.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the comments from Luis Mendo, I propose to use this command:

```
C=reshape(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, B), 1), size(B))
```

I think this is the fastest.

Comment: I'm think that this is pretty much the same as what I suggested, except that it's less clear what is going on. I'm fairly sure that under the hood MATLAB is doing the exact same thing with bsxfun as with the element-wise multiplication, and the permute/reshape difference is just splitting hairs.

Comment: Why `repmat`? `bsxfun` automatically does the repetition; in fact that's the essence of `bsxfun`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just do this:

```
C = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, B)));
```

This gives `C` with size M x L.